# Iterating over pairs in a list

Tags: equation-solving, sets, subset

Take a look at this code:

```
Do[
 Do[
  If[TrueQ[f1 != f2],
   If[SubsetQ[solutions[f2], solutions[f1]],
    Print[f1 \[Subset] f2]
    ]
   ],
  {f1, Keys[solutions]}
  ],
 {f2, Keys[solutions]}
]
```

`solutions` is an association from equations to their solutions. This code is supposed to print pairs of equation for which one's solutionset is a subset of the other. But it doesn't print anything. This is the `solutions` association I user:

```
<|-1 + x^2 == 0 -> {-1, 1}, 
(-1 + x)^2 == 0 -> {1}, 
8 + x == 9 -> {1},
x - 2 x^2 + x^3 == 2 -> {2},
(8 + x)^2 == 81 -> {-17, 1},
(16 x + x^2)^2 == 289 -> {-17, 1, -8 - Sqrt[47], -8 + Sqrt[47]}|>
```

As you can see, there are some solutionsets which are subsets of the others, but the above code doesn't print anything. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Try `f1 =!= f2` instead of `f1 != f2`.

Comment: BTW, only one `Do` is necessary.

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ How?

Comment: @saga `Do[If[TrueQ[f1 =!= f2], 
  If[SubsetQ[solutions[f2], solutions[f1]], 
   Print[f1 \[Subset] f2]]], {f1, Keys[solutions]}, {f2, 
  Keys[solutions]}]`

Comment: @saga One `Do` returns a tidier result, as I see it. Actually, `TrueQ` is also redundant.